# MySQL through SSH Tunnel

Tags: mysql, security, linux-networking, ssh-tunnel

I have a php web application (Server A) that accesses MySQL on a remote server (Server B) through an SSH tunnel. Once the tunnel is set up, I can log in and run queries on Server B from Server A exactly as you would expect. However, when the web application tries to query the server I get the error:

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [3159] Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.
```

Sure enough if I set the [require_secure_transport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_require_secure_transport) system variable to OFF, it all works as expected but I do not understand why the web application connection triggers this exception but a normal connection does not.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is just the default setting of the connection security in the PDO adapter that is different than settings used when connecting with MySQL client.